# Can I predict values in the future with a Keras NN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, prediction

I created a NN with Keras using the code below and it works great when comparing with the test data. But how can I use this model to actually predict future values? In my dataset I have two years of data with 1 observation per hour, and I want to predict the next week (next 128 observations) or maybe just the next day would be fine. How can I do this? I can only find answers to this when using RNN, which is not my case.

```
reg = Sequential()

reg.add(Dense(8,input_dim=1,kernel_initializer='ones',activation='linear',use_bias=False))
reg.add(Dense(64,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',activation='sigmoid',use_bias=False))
reg.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',activation='linear',use_bias=False))

reg.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
reg.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=100)

ytest_pred = reg.predict(xtest)
```

Comment: you need to have an lstm as output layer too. take a look at encoder-decoder networks for a begining.

Comment: your reg.predict() is able to make out of sample prediction, you just have to pass some input data with time periods outside your sample

Comment: models are build to predict unknown data. similar to `xtest` , preprocess your data(the one you want to predict)  in a similar way you build xtest and then feed it to the model. predict.

Comment: @user14518362 sorry I forgot to mention that I am using as an input to fit the model the variable itself that I want to predict. xtrain is the original data and ytrain is the data with a lag of 1 observation. so in my case I do not have any input data to use in reg.predict() since I want to predict the future.

Comment: @LucasMagalhães from what I understand you have some data in xtrain for t, t+1, ..., t+n-1 and your ytrain is the same data for  t+1, t+2, ..., t+n based on that if you want to make a prediction for futur data you can use your data for t+n as an input to predict t+n+1 and then use your prediction for t+n+1 to predict t+n+2 and so on